# swapping of data between sim card

Tags: dual-sim

My Micromax A350 has problem of swapping data. I have data pack in SIM2 when I am using continuously data then it automatically swap to SIM1 and it will start browsing using SIM1 because of that problem many times my balance is deducted.
I am suffering with this problem since I have formate my phone.
Thank You

Comment: specify more details like do you use 2g or 3g when this happens.

Comment: Actually i am using 2g data in SIM2 then it automatically swap to SIM1 which is working on 3g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find WCDMA AND GSM in your sim settings.
WCDMA (Wideband Code Division Multiplexing Access) and GSM are two technologies that are used in mobile telecommunications. The difference between these two is that GSM is a 2G technology and WCDMA is a part of the newer 3G group of technologies.
switch sim 1 to GSM only
and  sim 2 to wcdma and gsm  auto connect .
If these don't then another suitable combination would definitely work. (You will have to give them a try)

If none of the above work, reset your phone again.